# unzip a file using ssis

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I have a script task within a Foreach Loop Container to loop through every .zip file and extract it into the holding folder. In the script task I have this code to unzip the files

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string zipfullpath = Dts.Variables["User::ZipFullPath"].Value.ToString();
        string inputfolder = Dts.Variables["$Package::DownloadDirectory"].Value.ToString();

        using (ZipArchive arch = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipfullpath))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in arch.Entries)
            {
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(inputfolder, entry.FullName));
            }
        }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

however when I run the container I have this error

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

I believe it has something to do with the connection?

Comment: Check to see if you are referencing a variable that has not been selected in the Script Task edit window. In some cases this specific error ends up having nothing to do with what the error is referencing. Yay Microsoft.

Comment: Dts.Variables["$Package::DownloadDirectory"].Value.ToString(); looks a bit dodgy - try Dts.Variables["User::DownloadDirectory"].Value.ToString();

Comment: in the script task put a break point at the top and debug/step through it so you can see exactly where the error happens.